# Bug? Version 13.2.0 GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{"\[AlignmentMarker]"}}...} "Tabs" the first column after upgrade from 12.0

Tags: formatting, alignment, upgrade

After upgrading to 13.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) I have found that Grid boxes with columns aligned on AlignmentMarker are acting as if there is a Tab in front of the column.

For example, the Cell shown below produces

[image]

If I put a '+' in front of the alignment marker of the top row, it aligns properly.

[image]

```
Cell[BoxData[
 FormBox[
  RowBox[{"[", GridBox[{
     {
      RowBox[{"\[AlignmentMarker]", 
       RowBox[{"Cos", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}]}], 
      RowBox[{"\[AlignmentMarker]", 
       RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}]}]},
     {
      RowBox[{"-", "\[AlignmentMarker]", 
       RowBox[{"Sin", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}]}], 
      RowBox[{"\[AlignmentMarker]", 
       RowBox[{"Cos", "[", "\[Theta]", "]"}]}]}
    },
    GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{"\[AlignmentMarker]"}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}}], "]"}],
 TraditionalForm]], "Equation"]
```

I'm guessing this is a bug.  I have 96 notebooks with stuff like this in them
[image]

I already had to rewrite my file processing code because the new file manipulation features don't work with my old code.  I really don't want to edit all of these notebooks to work around something that will be fixed.

Is this a known defect that is being worked on?  Is there a global setting to fix the problem?

Comment: Changing to `"Columns" -> {{Baseline}}` the extra spaces disappear. You may try search and modify the `GridBoxAlignment` entry in the option inspector.

Comment: But that doesn't align on AlignmentMarker